# FlinkKafkaConsumer09 reads some of the messages again and again

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have written a simple program to read data from Kafka and print in flink. Below is the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Options flinkPipelineOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().as(Options.class);

    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    Class<?> unmodColl = Class.forName("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection");
    env.getConfig().addDefaultKryoSerializer(unmodColl, UnmodifiableCollectionsSerializer.class);
    env.enableCheckpointing(1000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);

    flinkPipelineOptions.setJobName("MyFlinkTest");
    flinkPipelineOptions.setStreaming(true);
    flinkPipelineOptions.setCheckpointingInterval(1000L);
    flinkPipelineOptions.setNumberOfExecutionRetries(5);
    flinkPipelineOptions.setExecutionRetryDelay(3000L);

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
    p.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    p.setProperty("group.id", "test");

    FlinkKafkaConsumer09<Notification> kafkaConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>("testFlink",new ProtoDeserializer(),p);

    DataStream<Notification> input = env.addSource(kafkaConsumer);

    input.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<Notification, String>() {
        @Override
        public String map(Notification value) throws Exception {
            return "Kafka and Flink says: " + value.toString();
        }

    }).print();

    env.execute();
}
```

I need flink to process my data in kafka exactly once and I have few questions on how it can be done.

- When does FlinkKafkaConsumer09 commits the processed offsets to kafka?
- Say my topic has 10 messages, the consumer processes all 10 messages. When I stop the job and start it again, it starts processing random messages from the set of previously read messages. I need to ensure none of my messages are processed twice.

Please advice. Appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This page describes the [fault tolerance guarantees of the Flink Kafka connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-and-fault-tolerance).

You can use [Flink's savepoints to re-start a job in an exactly-once (state preserving) manner](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/savepoints.html).

The reason why you are seeing the messages again is because the offsets committed by Flink to the Kafka broker / Zookeeper are not in line with Flink's registered state.
You'll always see messages processed multiple times after restore / failure in Flink, even with exactly-once **semantics** enabled. The [exactly-once guarantees in Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/fault_tolerance.html) are with respect to registered state, not for the records send to the operators.

---

Slightly off-topic: What are these lines for? They are not passed to Flink anywhere.

```
Options flinkPipelineOptions = PipelineOptionsFactory.create().as(Options.class);
flinkPipelineOptions.setJobName("MyFlinkTest");
flinkPipelineOptions.setStreaming(true);
flinkPipelineOptions.setCheckpointingInterval(1000L);
flinkPipelineOptions.setNumberOfExecutionRetries(5);
flinkPipelineOptions.setExecutionRetryDelay(3000L);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response rmetzger. Sorry the flinkPipelineOptions was provided for dataflow runner and I forgot to remove those. I read through the tutorials you have pointed out but still not clear on how I can save the state and resume the next time. If possible any example would really help me. Thanks and appreciate your help.